# matrix function differentiation

Tags: matrix-calculus

I have this simple function $Z=f(Q)=AQ$  where $A$ is a $1\times n$ matrix and $Q$ is $n\times m$ matrix of variables 
I want to calculate derivative of $Z$ with respect to $Q$. (In the reference that  I read the answer is $A^T$.

This equation is part of neural network back propagation algorithm and I really want to understand where this answer came from .

Perhaps my question is not formulated well because mathematics is not main interest

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat ill-defined, because the derivative of a vector with respect to a matrix is (often) considered to be a 3D array. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044191/given-the-matrix-a-and-vector-x-what-is-the-partial-derivative-of-ax-with-respe?rq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621948/derivative-of-a-vector-with-respect-to-a-matrix).

But it can be made sense of in the following way. Let $Z=AQ$ where 
$A\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$, $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and so $Z\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times m}$. 
Then its components look like
$$
\Lambda^k_{ij} = 
\frac{\partial Z_k}{\partial Q_{ij}}
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial Q_{ij}}
\sum_\ell A_\ell Q_{\ell k}
=
\sum_\ell A_\ell\delta_{i\ell}\delta_{jk}
$$
But now notice that *all the components are zero except when $j=k$*. 
Notice also that, once we assume $j=k$, there is no longer any dependence on $j$ or $k$. 
So let's just ignore those components and consider
$$
\Psi_i=
\Lambda^k_{ik} = 
\frac{\partial Z_k}{\partial Q_{ik}} = \sum_\ell A_\ell \delta_{i\ell}
=A_i
$$
If we let $\Psi\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$, then we can define
$$
\Psi := \frac{\partial Z}{\partial Q}
=A^T
$$